# PHP Данные не полностью отправляются на сервер

Tags: php, post

Имеется форма, которая может содержать много данных, вида:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="item[n][id]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="item[n][datestamp]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="item[n][visible_slot]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="item[n][title]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="item[n][price]" value=""></div>
    <input type="text" name="item[n][sizes]" value=""></div>
    <textarea name="item[n][description]"></textarea>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="item[n][visible_img][k]" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="item[n][photo][k]" value="">
      </div>
      ... k+1 < 10
    </div>
  </div>
  ... n+1
</form>
```

Пример данных

```
$_POST['item'][262] => Array
  (
    [id] => 71424
    [datestamp] => 1610099549
    [visible_slot] => true
    [title] => ...
    [price] => ...
    [sizes] => ...
    [description] => ...
    [visible_img] => Array
      (
        [0] => true
        [1] => true
        [2] => true
        [3] => false
        [4] => true
      )

    [photo] => Array
      (
        [0] => https://sun9-8.userapi.com/impf/Q13JyX8Q...um
        [1] => https://sun9-70.userapi.com/impf/rTli...pe=album
        [2] => https://sun9-36.userapi.com/impf/jJ...=album
        [3] => https://sun9-7.userapi.com/impf/r...type=album
      )
)
```

Значений может быть больше чем 262 (это последние полученное значение), с меньшим количеством все отправлялось целиком.
С менял (в .htaccess и в php.ini) `post_max_size` результата не дало. Форма отправляется `submit`ом. Что еще может ограничивать передачу и с чем может быть связанно?

P.S. Ошибок на стороне клиента нет, на сервере просто дампил в файл

Comment: если приходит часть данных, то это `max_input_vars`, но оно по дефолту 1000. должно бы хватать.

Comment: оно там впрочем E_WARNING генерирует, если превышается лимит.

Comment: @teran да, дело было в этом, спасибо! Оно стояло на 5000, причем увеличил до 5001 и конечное значение уже почему то было не 263, а 265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Максимальное число принимаемых сервером переменных регулируется параметром `max_input_vars` конфигурации php.ini.

> Сколько входных переменных может быть принято в одном запросе (ограничение накладывается на каждую из глобальных переменных $_GET, $_POST и $_COOKIE отдельно). Использование этой директивы снижает вероятность сбоев в случае атак с использованием хеш-коллизий. Если входных переменных больше, чем задано директивой, выбрасывается предупреждение E_WARNING, а **все последующие переменные в запросе игнорируются**.

© https://www.php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php

каждое поле вашего массива - отдельная переменная запроса. Так что при превышении установленного числа все остальное вы теряете.

В случае, если производите редактирование некой таблицы, и отправляете все изменения на сервер "пачкой", то лучше измените логику на использование аякса и сохранения по-одной строке за раз.